# Win 10 PC keeps switching between Analog and HDMI signals and does not start except after pull out and replug graphics card

Tags: boot, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

For a couple of weeks now my PC does not boot properly and I have massive problems pinpointing the problem. I hope you guys can help me.

When I try to boot it, the display stays black and the signal switches between HDMI and Analog.

**Sometimes PC starts, sometimes it does not.**

I thought it is a problem with the graphics card (**NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070, 6 months old**).
So I removed it and tried it in my brothers PC, which also did not boot with my graphics card. Same problem applies, while my PC boots perfectly fine without a graphics card.

I replaced the **RTX 2070** with my old **GTX 1050Ti** and had no problems at first. After a week or two the same problem started to appear. Sometimes the PC starts without problems sometimes it doesn't.

Now, when I pull the graphics card out of the mainboard and plug it back in, **the computer starts, 100% of the time**. This works only for the **GTX** and not for the **RTX**.

A couple of months ago I tried to **overclock my CPU** (**i5-4690K**) and did so successfully. The same day I **reset my BIOS** because I actually didn't need an OCed CPU.
Is it possible that the overclocking damaged my mainboard and/or my graphics cards?
What could be the problem with my setup?

The most important components:

- **GPU 1:** EVGA GeForce GTX 1050Ti
- **GPU 2:** 8GB MSI GeForce RTX 2070 Gaming Z 8G
- **Mainboard:** ASRock Z87-Extreme3
- **CPU:** Intel Core i5-4690K
- **PSU:** be quiet! System Power 8 - 600W

**UPDATE**
After a while, now the second/my old graphics card gave up on me. The workaround with pulling it out and placing it back in doesn't do anything anymore.

In that case there must be something **really** wrong with the mainboard, right?

Is it somehow possible that the mainboard pumps too much energy to the GPU and breaks it after a while?

Comment: This may sound like a daft question - You haven't got 2 cables going into your monitor from the PC have you?

Comment: Your psu is likely insufficient.

Comment: Does your motherboard have on board graphics? Are you plugging the monitor into the MoBo output or the GFX card output?

Comment: @Smock nope, one standard HDMI cable

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia but it worked without any issues before, what might have changed?

Comment: @Smock well... When removing the graphics card I plug the cable into the mainboard

Comment: @VIC What changed is the age of the PSU - they loose power with time - and aggravated by the additional stress of OC. Real 600W is hardly enough for your hardware.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia ok I understand but there are still a couple of things I do not understand. 1) It is "only" about 2 years old... do you really need to switch it out every couple of years? 2) I overclocked just once because I was curious 3) The PSU my brother has is 650W strong and fairly new

Comment: That RTX 2070 is a 225W card and recommends use of a 550W PSU. 600W should be enough to at least power on the PC. I would expect other instabilities creeping in in that setup if it was insufficient. What's odd is that this seems to also happen with the 1050Ti (Am I reading that right?) which is a far less power hungry card (300W max)

Comment: Incidentally, the [EVGA Wattage checker](https://www.evga.com/power-meter/) suggests 450W PSUs for this setup.

Comment: @Smock Yes, exactly, as I said, I didn't have any problems with booting before - power shouldn't be the issue. Yes, you read that right: The 1050Ti has the exact same problem. The only difference is, that I can use the "re plug" workaround with it to get the PC to boot. Is it possible that the overclocking somehow fried my RTX and the mainboard? That is pretty much the only thing I can think of

Comment: I had an electrical issue with a graphics card once that took out my motherboard and PSU with it, so it's possible there's a knock on effect - hard to tell from here though. Are you sure the GFX cards are properly seated when they are inserted? (have you got standoffs between case and motherboard etc)

Comment: @Smock I fixated the motherboard by screwing it onto the dedicated 'pins' on the case. The graphics cards sit as firmly and perfectly as I can get them to. I also tried the second PCIe slot - no difference here.